# portrait to landscape Video viewand controller restart problam in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I have a `videoView` that i control it by `MediaController`
it work well but when user change there phone position rotate in portrait to landscope mode or (upside down in landscope to portrait)[image: video view]

it will restart in first of video again

for more understanding I have take a video pleas watch it
see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtlzTqtc7zg&feature=youtu.be

**my xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**my MainActivity.class**

```
package sirwansoft.safir.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);

        //control media
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        //set view with controller
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        //set Controller to view
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: When rotated, on resume is called, starting again. Or you prohibit this to happen or you know realtime the playing position (in h:m:s) and, when onresume is called, you jump to the last recorded position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code to your AndroidManifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name="YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME"
    android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
/>
```